Magnetic energy terms of system of three circuits
Say we've got a system of coplanar circuits like in the picture with same electric current flowing through them

We know that a system of circuits has magnetic energy
$$\mathcal U_{\,\mathrm m}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}M_{ij}I_i I_j=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i}\Phi_i I_i,$$
noting that $M_{ij}=M_{ji}$ and that $M_{ii}=L$.
Then, what I wanted to know was what term $M_{ij}I_jI_k$ (for $i\neq j$) that contributes to the magnetic energy is positive and which is negative. Namely, making use of $M_{ij}=M_{ji}$ to reduce number of terms, which of these is positive?: $M_{12}I_1 I_2$, $M_{13}I_1I_3$ and $M_{23}I_2I_3$.

$\mathbf{ATTEMPT}$
First of all I think we should define a sign convention for each circuit's intensity: counter-clockwise shall be positive, and clockwise, negative. This means $I_1<0$, $I_2<0$ and $I_3>0$. As for those terms, it is equivalent to say in the language of fluxes, respectively, $\Phi_{12} I_1$, $\Phi_{13}I_1$ and $\Phi_{23}I_2$, where
$$\Phi_{ij}=\iint_S\mathbf B_j\cdot\,\mathrm d\mathbf S_i,$$
and where the direction of the surface vector for circuit $i$ is the same as the magnetic field generated by the same circuit so that $\Phi_{ii}>0$ (I'm not sure if the surface vector should be the same for all circuits or if what I did is "legal").
Hence, using this definitions we obtain $\Phi_{12}<0$, $\Phi_{13}>0$, $\Phi_{23}>0$. In brief,
$$\begin{aligned}
&M_{12}I_1 I_2>0\\
&M_{13}I_1 I_3<0\\
&M_{23}I_2 I_3<0
\end{aligned}$$
I'm not sure if I proceeded accordingly or if I made any mistakes, let me know...

The signs you have found for the three energy terms are incorrect. It looks like you have determined the wrong signs for the fluxes and I don't know why, so I'll try to explain from the beginning.
For each loop, you need to choose an orientation, which also defines the orientation of the surface (bounded by that loop) on which you integrate to determine the flux. Usually, the directions are labeled like in your diagram, according to which loop 1 would be clockwise-oriented, loop 2 clockwise, and loop 3 counter-clockwise (I'll come back to your approach of defining each to be counter-clockwise.). This means that a magnetic flux into the page is positive for loops 1 and 2, and negative for loop 3.
Now, a positive (i.e. clockwise) $I_1$ produces a flux out of the page in loops 2 and 3 (the field is inward inside loop 1 and outward outside). This means that $\Phi_{12} = M_{12}I_1 < 0$ and $\Phi_{13} = M_{13}I_1 > 0$, so $M_{12} < 0$ and $M_{13} > 0$ (since we started out assuming $I_1 > 0$). You can similarly conclude $M_{23} > 0$. Now that you have the signs of all the mutual inductances, you can determine the sign of each term using the sign of each current. If the currents are all positive, the signs of the three terms should be the opposite of what you have found.
If we were to define all loops as being counter-clockwise-oriented (flux positive when out of page), then a counter-clockwise current in any loop produces an inward (negative) flux in any other, so all mutual inductances are negative. Using $I_1 < 0$, $I_2 < 0$ and $I_3 > 0$, you can once again conclude that the signs of the terms are the opposite of what you have found.

Thanks a lot again. I realized my mistake too: I chose different $\mathrm d\mathbf S$ for each loop when instead it should've been the same for all three. I solved it basically by choosing the $\mathrm d\mathbf S$ out of page (for example) and if the magnetic field generated by the loop had the same direction (counter-clockwise intensity), then the intensity would be positive and viceversa. I'd finally end up with the same conclusion as yours.

@Conreu Just to stress in case it's not clear: the direction of $d\mathbf{S}$ and the loop orientation are not independent and must be consistent. In other words, you choose one of them, which determines the other. Since $d\mathbf{S}$ out of page is consistent with counter-clockwise loops, your approach works. You could not have chosen $d\mathbf{S}$ into page, unless the loops were defined clockwise-oriented.
